# Weak-Strong, Lipschitz and uniform continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

In our lecture of stationary differential equations with the theory of monotone operators we introduced the concept of weak-strong continuity with sequences:

> **Defintion (weak-strong continuity)**
>   Let $V$ be a reflexive Banach space.
>   A (not not necessarily linear) operator $A: V \to V^*$ ($V^*$ is the continuous dual space) is called weak-strong continuous if
>   $$
> v_n \rightharpoonup v \text{ in } V
> \implies A v_n \to Av \text{ in } V^* 
> $$
>   for all sequences $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$.

This is obviously a stronger requirement than continuity.

Since uniform and Lipschitz continuity are also stronger than continuity I wondered if there is a connection between them (as in: one implies the other under certain conditions) as i.e. $$\textrm{Lipschitz } \implies \textrm{ uniform } \implies \textrm{ continuous}$$on compact intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no connection between this properties in general.

First, let $A=Id$. This is a nice Lipschitz continuous and  uniformly continuous but not weak-strong continuous.

Second, for $V=\mathbb R$, $A(x)=x^2$ is weak-strong continuous but neither Lipschitz nor uniformly continuous.